# How can I push a Git repository to a folder over SSH?

Tags: git

I have a folder called my-project inside which I've done *git init*, *git commit -a*, etc.

Now I want to push it to an empty folder at /mnt/foo/bar on a remote server.

How can I do this?

I did try, based on what I'd read:

```
cd my-project
git remote add origin ssh://user@host/mnt/foo/bar/my-project.git
git push origin master
```

which didn't seem right (I'd assume source would come before destination) and it failed:

```
fatal: '/mnt/boxee/git/midwinter-physiotherapy.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'd like this to work such that I don't have to access the remote host and manually init a Git repository every time ... do I have to do that? Am I going down the right route at all?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The command is correct; however, the remote address must point to an initialized Git repository too. It's a one-time job, though.

```
ssh user@host "git init --bare /mnt/foo/bar/my-project.git"
```

(In Git, a "bare" repository is one without a working tree.)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to both push to the repo **and have the files update on the server**, you can create a server-side git hook to checkout the files after they've been pushed. In the **server** side git `/hooks/` directory create a file named `post-receive` and add the following code (updating the directories to match your folder structure):

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Then give the file proper permissions using `chmod +x post-receive`

**More info & a detailed explanation here:**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to use `ssh://user@host:/mnt/foo/bar/my-project` (note the `:` after the host, and remove `.git` at the end).

So I could clone a repository with:

```
git clone ssh://user@host:/mnt/foo/bar/my-project
```

We also can note that the format is like using `scp` command.

Comment: cloning works with this command but for me pushing again gives: ```remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable ....
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create the repository manually on the server, you could install [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way), which will automate the process. But you have to have some process on the server to create the repository -- you can't do it over a git ssh connection from the client.